# What is the difference between linux/if.h and net/if.h?

Tags: c, linux

The comments say that `net/if.h` is part of the GNU C Library and `linux/if.h` says it is "An implementation of the TCP/IP protocol suite for the LINUX operating system."

But why are there two of them and what is the use of each one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Initially, both provide data structures to manage network interfaces.`linux/if.h` is specifically more related to interact with Linux kernel's network interfaces. Actually, it states so at the beginning of the file:

```
/*
 * INET     An implementation of the TCP/IP protocol suite for the LINUX
 *      operating system.  INET is implemented using the  BSD Socket
 *      interface as the means of communication with the user level.
 *
 *      Global definitions for the INET interface module.
 */
```

`net/if.h` is glibc's file for same purpose and is initially more `user space` focused.

Is important to note that, if you're going to use both (they share some structures but not all), include order is quite important, suggesting, in most cases, to include `linux/if.h` before `net/if.h`.

Answer (score 5):

`linux/if.h` is part of the kernel (or imported in the libc from the kernel), and `net/if.h` is part of the C library.

Thus, `net/if.h` is what your processes can see, and `linux/if.h` what the kernel wants. The kernel internals (which doesn't see libc) include the kernel headers. `net/if.h` is what your hardcore networking tool includes. :-)

Far-far ago there were incompatibility problems between the two. This resulted f.e. don't working ifconfig, etc. tools. Currently (since around 10-15 yrs) they are well integrated and backward compatible.