# mmap implementation in glibc - dynamic library with symbol mmap

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls, mmap

I wanted to see how the Linux kernel function `mmap()` is implemented, so I downloaded the GNU C Library (`glibc`) source from the [GNU page](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/). (I downloaded `glibc-2.27` because `ldd --version` told me I was using `GLIBC 2.27`)
Now to find the definition of `mmap()` I did `grep -r "mmap(void" *` which returned nothing, so I tried `grep -r "mmap (void" *` which returned the following:

```
conform/data/sys/mman.h-data:function {void*} mmap (void*, size_t, int, int, int, off_t)
include/sys/mman.h:extern void *__mmap (void *__addr, size_t __len, int __prot,
malloc/memusage.c:mmap (void *start, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)
manual/llio.texi:@deftypefun {void *} mmap (void *@var{address}, size_t @var{length}, int @var{protect}, int @var{flags}, int @var{filedes}, off_t @var{offset})
misc/sys/mman.h:extern void *mmap (void *__addr, size_t __len, int __prot,
misc/mmap.c:__mmap (void *addr, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)
support/xunistd.h:void *xmmap (void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd);
support/xmmap.c:xmmap (void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd)
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap.c:__mmap (void *addr, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)
sysdeps/mach/hurd/dl-sysdep.c:__mmap (void *addr, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)
sysdeps/mach/hurd/mmap.c:__mmap (void *addr, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)
```

Of all the results that were about `mmap()` and not about `__mmap()` I found that the definition of `mmap()` is in `malloc/memusage.c` which defined `mmap()` as the following:

```
/* `mmap' replacement.  We do not have to keep track of the size since
   `munmap' will get it as a parameter.  */
void *
mmap (void *start, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset)
{
  void *result = NULL;

  /* Determine real implementation if not already happened.  */
  if (__glibc_unlikely (initialized <= 0))
    {
      if (initialized == -1)
        return NULL;

      me ();
    }

  /* Always get a block.  We don't need extra memory.  */
  result = (*mmapp)(start, len, prot, flags, fd, offset);

  ...

  /* Return the pointer to the user buffer.  */
  return result;
}
```

I figured `result = (*mmapp)(start, len, prot, flags, fd, offset);` is what matters, and in this file there are two other parts that deal with this `mmapp` function pointer, which are:

1. declaration: `static void *(*mmapp) (void *, size_t, int, int, int, off_t);`
2. initialization in some function called `me()`: `mmapp = (void *(*)(void *, size_t, int, int, int, off_t))dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "mmap");`
   The `dlsym()` function, according to [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym), takes a "handle" of a dynamic library returned by dlopen() and the null-terminated symbol name, returning the address where that symbol is loaded into memory.

Thus, the whole process can be summarized as follows:

1. `mmap()` calls a function pointed to by the pointer `mmapp`
2. `mmapp` is set to point to the symbol `"mmap"` in a dynamic library loaded into memory

But I can't find any information on dynamic library with the symbol `"mmap"`.
Am I doing something wrong in the process of code analysis? I haven't much experience in code analysis, let alone looking into system call functions or kernel codes, so any advice or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: None of this is going to be very interesting to you, since at the bottom, all you're going to see in the library is a system call.  The real action here is all in the kernel.  See for instance https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/mmap.c.  But you might rather look at some older or "toy" OS in which the code may be much simpler and more readable.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hey I think this might actually be very helpful. But I think you can tell from my question that I'm not very familiar with Linux kernel stuff - I want to ask, in the manual for mmap it says we need to include <sys/mman.h> but there are no directory named sys in the git (there is linux/include/linux/mman.h but it doesn't have mmap definition nor declaration)... am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: It's too long a story for a comment.  Ask a separate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082433/what-is-the-difference-between-linux-if-h-and-net-if-h/20083006#20083006 is sort of relevant, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux kernel has multiple different `mmap` syscalls, and they're not the same across different versions and architectures. The libc `mmap` function abstracts that and presents the POSIX interface to its users. However, Glibc code is complicated by the fact that it also targets non-Linux platforms, and has codepaths for all parts of the `off_t`/`off64_t` transition (see [Glibc manual § Feature Test Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) for some more information about that). You'd have an easier time looking at an alternative minimal libc like musl which only targets modern Linux and doesn't aim for historical nor full POSIX compatibility.

In musl's case: prototype and constants are in [include/sys/mman.h](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/include/sys/mman.h). Implementation is in [src/mman/mmap.c](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/mman/mmap.c) which does some argument processing before handing off to `syscall(SYS_mmap2)` (in most cases).

In Glibc's case: prototype is in [misc/sys/mman.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=misc/sys/mman.h). Constants are scattered as not all platforms are the same; see [bits/mman.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=bits/mman.h), [sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/mman-shared.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/mman-shared.h), [sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/mman-map-flags-generic.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/mman-map-flags-generic.h), [sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/mman.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/bits/mman.h) for example. The actual definition is in [sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap.c), and like musl's, it does some argument processing before handing off to `syscall(SYS_mmap2)` (in most cases).

Either way, `mmap` in the libc can only work with kernel support. Hence @NateEldredge's comment that it's fairly uninteresting.

By the way, what you saw in [malloc/memusage.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/memusage.c) is *not* the definition of `mmap` that you are using. That gets built into a separate `libmemusage` library which intercepts `mmap` calls (among others) and adds some tracking around them. Your distribution may or may not ship this; if it does, you would have to opt-in to using it by running your program with `LD_PRELOAD=libmemusage.so` (which is effectively what the [memusage](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/memusage.sh) wrapper script does). That is why it is using `dlsym`: it is defining a replacement `mmap` symbol, but needs to look up the original `mmap` to be able to wrap calls to it.

Within the Linux kernel, `SYS_mmap2` is mapped to `sys_mmap_pgoff` on most architectures, defined in [mm/mmap.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/mmap.c) as

```c
SYSCALL_DEFINE6(mmap_pgoff, unsigned long, addr, unsigned long, len,
        unsigned long, prot, unsigned long, flags,
        unsigned long, fd, unsigned long, pgoff)
```

If given a file descriptor, it results in calling the

```c
struct file {
    const struct file_operations {
        int (*mmap) (struct file *, struct vm_area_struct *);
    } *f_op;
}
```

callback (from [include/linux/fs.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/fs.h)) when defined by the filesystem providing that file. These have various different implementations, but in general they add a new vma to the process's pagetable which either makes other kernel machinery map specific pages into the process, or makes pagefaults within that area calling back into the filesystem to provide a page to be mapped at that time.